If we find homophones, how do we decide whether or not they are different words?
This seems to have an easy resolution for situations its perhaps semantically or syntactically obvious (like can as in container vs can, or no vs know) that we have more than one word. But I got to thinking about this question after seeing a post claiming "all together" and "altogether' are exact homophones in American English. There was some light discussion about the phonetics and phonology there, but it made me wonder-if these are exact homophones why not assume there's actually just a polysemous word (both terms do a sort of total grouping of something), and to the more general question of how do we determine if homophones aren't actually the same word?

In that particular case, the fact that all together can be split up by other words (e.g., ‘all closely together’), whereas altogether cannot, is pretty conclusive evidence that they’re not the same word. In a more general sense, it is indeed not always obvious. It’s not uncommon to see dictionaries list multiple homophonous words and note that the origin of X (2) is as a semantic extension of X (1), for example.
